# mousedown JQuery doesn't work on Android touchpad

Tags: jquery, android, touch

I used mousedown event as hope that it will work when a user touches the element but it didn't seem to show the effect on andriod tablet. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, onclick mouse handler. On a touch, Android first fires all touch events followed by mouse events to support more devices. Hence, if you want better performance, try "ontouchstart" and "ontouchend" as well.

Answer (score 0):

By using a different event. I'd guess something like `focus` might do for you, but it is hard to say without the goal mentioned.

Comment: I would simply like to change colour or icon of buttons to a different one so I´ve been using mouseup, mousedown, mouseover and mouseout. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think using `OnClick` event your problem will get solve.

Answer (score 0):

that's because when you touch your screen you are not firing a onmousedown event.
You should try onclick or ondrag or maybe even onmouseover.